# capture windows username in asp.net mvc request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have an intranet app asp.net mvc site.  is there anyway to capture the windows nt login from the user wihtout having a full login system in the site.   i dont want permissioning but i would like to do some logging on the server to track requests, etc . .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` if you set up the site to use [Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx). Many browsers will pass the username on transparently.

Comment: it seems with firefox, it prompts for a user name / pwd even though IE seems to not require it . . any ideas on why this is happenning

Comment: FireFox, by default, doesn't pass on the username. However, it can be made to work - see http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/

Comment: It's not that IE doesn't require it, it's that IE does it silently behind the scenes.  Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc will all require you to enter your domain username and password.  That's just how it is.  The nice thing is that at least you don't have to code a logon form.

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
 var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

it returns Domail/User

Do not forget to put this in web.Config

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

Comment: This should only be done if you understand the implications of impersonation. Many times this isn't a good solution and is overkill for just getting the username of the client.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Web.Config file for your application (be sure it's the main one, not the Web.Config under Views), remark out `<authentication mode="Forms">` if you see it, then add lines like this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authorization>
  <allow roles="DOMAIN\PersonnelGroup" />
  <allow users="DOMAIN\jdoe"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

You don't have to include the `<authorization>` section but it's useful if you want to allow access for certain groups and users, and deny everyone else. When you use IE, the credentials get passed along automatically. You can test this by printing the username in your view:

```
@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

If you open your site using Firefox or any other browser besides IE, it will prompt you for the username and password because it's not automatically passing along the credentials (although apparently you can get Firefox to pass along the credentials, as Dan Diplo mentions above).

If you want to pass these credentials along to another server, such as a SQLServer, it becomes more of a headache from my experience, because you run into a double hop issue. The only workaround I know of is to host IIS and SqlServer on the same server, or have a login for your intranet so you have the username and password to pass along to SQLServer.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Windows is this mvc app running on?

You could try the following:

- Use IIS Manager to disable anonymous access to the site, and make sure digest and/or windows authentication is enabled.
- Change the mvc app's web.config to use Windows Authentication
- Access the login name in the controller using User.Identity.Name.

Would that do?

Answer (score 0):

If you set IIS to use Windows Authentication and the site is in the Intranet Zone for your clients then the logins will automatically happen without any prompts at all.

Comment: What if we want conditional login, such as requiring a Windows (re) login only if users go into the app's Administration menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch user's name with the following piece of code:

```
var userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

`User.Identity` is automatically populated if you use any authentication (example: cookie based, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
var MachineName = HttpContext.Server.MachineName;
var BrowserName = HttpContext.Request.Browser;
var Ip Address = HttpContext.UserHostAddress;
```

You can get information with these codes.