# how do you capture httpcontext user information in your controller code when using visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, httpcontext

i asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132807/capture-windows-username-in-asp-net-mvc-request/2132841#2132841) which allowed me to capture user by using:

```
string userName = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

in my controller code.

One issue i have is that when testing in visual studio it shows up as an empty string.  I want to track this field for my testing.

Is there anyway to have this work in the local ASP.net webserver process on my machine so it it will mimic windows authentication on my server ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run application under IIS and set windows authentication in web.config.

```
    <authentication mode="Windows">
```

Comment: i added the actual line in web.config to be explicit but thanks for pointing me in the right direction