# Identity.Name is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

My MVC application,

Decorated controller with

> ```
> [AuthorizedRoles(Roles = "Manager")]
> ```

and I am trying to get the requested user name using HttpContextBase

> ```
>   public class AuthorizedRoles : AuthorizeAttribute
>   {
>     protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>     {
>        httpContext.User.Identity.Name
> ```

Why Identity.Name is null ?

Web.config looks like

> ```
> <authentication mode="Windows" />
> <authorization>
>   <allow users="*"/>
> </authorization>
> ```

Please help to get the request User ..

Comment: Has the user actually logged on when you are trying this? So you have an Authentication cookie already? You will only actually get access to the "Logged In User" details after they logged in.

Comment: I am trying to get the windows logged in user. My application accessed directly by URL. No login page

Comment: I am able to get requested user with domain name using
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity

Comment: But still not clear why HttpContextBase Identity Name is null?

Comment: Are you using Firefox?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132807/capture-windows-username-in-asp-net-mvc-request

Comment: No, I am using IE 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is what you need to do!

[image]

I don't know what to set in the web.config - but changing these options makes it work. to get this screen select you project and press 'F4'

EDIT: I imagine you will need to configure this in IIS when you host the site as well.
This might help in the web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    ....
    <security>
      <authentication >
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```