# Windows Authentication on the Server hosted on the Azure which is added to the domain

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, windows-authentication

I have an application on MVC 5 with form authentication, hosted on windows server(2012) which is on Azure. Also this server is added to the domain.

My client has asked me to use windows credentials to authenticate the user instead of Form authentication.

So, I changed my web.config entry for the authentication as follows:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>     
  <identity impersonate="true" />    
</system.web>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>               
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="true">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add value="NTLM" />
                <add value="Negotiate" />
            </providers>
            <extendedProtection tokenChecking="Allow" />
        </windowsAuthentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />

    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Rest of the IIS  v-8.5) settings are as follows:

- Apllication Pool: Classic with 4.0
- .Net Version in Code: 4.5
- Windows authentication enabled
- Anonymous authentication disabled
- Form authentication disabled

Still, I'm not able to get Windows user email or username form any of the following:

```
uname=User.Identity.Name;
uname=UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
uname= Environment.UserName;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name since your config is set to use Windows Authentication. Many browsers will pass the username on transparently.

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132807/capture-windows-username-in-asp-net-mvc-request) for some additional workarounds.

Comment: But doesn't it return Identity of the user logged on to the site, not on the machine?